# Replacement for XNA?

Tags: xna, c#, xbox, microsoft

Since Microsoft stopped developing XNA I'm wondering what will be the replacement for the XBox 720°. 
I've been wondering about this. XNA was THE technologie the XBox, easy and powerfull.

So is Microsoft developing a new technologie or are they going to continue XNA, even if they've said they'd stop.

Comment: I suspect the only accurate answer to this question is "Nobody that can discuss it in public knows yet".

Comment: If you're concerned about XNA dying because you like XNA, I suggest you check out MonoGame. At worst, it's XNA on Windows (including Windows 8, which MS XNA never supported); at best, it works on mobile, too (Android/iPhone) if you are willing to shell out some cash.

Comment: No I'm just curious. I thought I've more success if I ask here ( but I also googled yet ) because here are alot of proffesional game-developers and maybe someone knows somthing 'bout it?
Well ok, if Nobody knows, ok, thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody knows what they have planned as far as indie games are going. Neither do I think XNA will ever be on the Xbox 720. The thing is that it might now be easy for Microsoft to manage developers they never met in person. I would say they might come up with something although there are still arcade games which if your willing to official publish your game you might be able to post it as an arcade game.